# Need some help on petri nets?

Tags: mathematical-modeling

Here's the question:

$\qquad$ [image: pic]

How do we go about doing this ? I have very little knowledge on petri nets. Can someone answer it for me ? (And regarding the program part , just give me an idea on what to do maybe like an algorithm?)

Thanks so much !

Comment: FWIW: [petri net](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net). (Didn't know what it was until I looked it up.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for answers to your question, please consider the following. You should also consider [an interactive version of the following images](http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/Juggalox$1419730749.pdf).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]